# Calculate the first order derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How to solve the following limit?

$$f(x)=\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^x$$

I searched for a hint that if we change this function to $f(x)=e^{\ln\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^x}$ but how to do it later?

Thank you.

Comment: Where does $x$ tend to?

Comment: Where does your $x$ go ?

Comment: Your title says "first order derivative" but your question text asks to "solve the following limit". Which is it? If it's the latter, what is the limit?

Comment: Excuse me, my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's write 
$$f(x) = \left( \frac{x}{1+x} \right) ^x = \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1+x} \right)^x = \exp \left( x \ln \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1+x} \right) \right)$$

When $x \rightarrow +\infty$, you have 
$$\ln \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1+x} \right)  \sim - \frac{1}{1+x} $$

so

$$x \ln \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1+x} \right)  \sim - \frac{x}{1+x} \rightarrow -1$$

You get that
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f(x) = \frac{1}{e}$$